# I have created MasterDetailPage in MvvmCross, the click(Command) is not working on detail page

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have created an mvvm cross application in which I have created a viewmodel as well as a page with xaml.cs. So the view model is not being called from page(xaml) command or the navigation is not working.

I have attached the command :

```
public IMvxAsyncCommand LblTappedNumberCommand => new 
MvxAsyncCommand(async 
 () =>
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<AddPhoneNumberViewModel>();
});
```

Xaml for above :

```
  <Image Source="user.png">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
  <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding 
  EditProfileClicked}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>
```

By removing MasterDetailPage(sidebar) above code works properly.

When I write a code for click event in xaml.cs like below it works:

xaml.cs :

```
public void EditProfileClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new EditProfile1Page());
}
```

xaml :

```
<Image  
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="End"                  
    Source="user.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="EditProfileClicked" 
NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see there you are binding the command of the image to `EditProfileClicked` and you should be binding to `LblTappedNumberCommand`.